# ¿Como funcionan las listas en SWI-PROLOG?, ¿Como traer un dato de una lista para hacer operaciones aritmeticas?, ¿Como actualizo un dato en una lista?

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

Necesito entender como funcionan las listas en Prolog ya que busco una forma de crear unas listas con 3 elementos, es decir, Lista1=[No. de Cuenta, NIP, Saldo]; similar a lo que es un array en otros lenguajes. Estas listas deben permitirme hacer evaluaciones de inicio de sesión donde el No. de cuenta de la lista 1 coincida con el NIP de la lista 1; también requiero realizar actualizaciones del Saldo mediante operaciones aritmeticas que simulen retiros o depositos y a su vez, debo hacer traspasos de Saldo, donde retire una cantidad del Saldo de la lista 1 y se lo agregue a la cantidad del Saldo de la lista 2 y viceversa.

Adjunto un codigo base que tengo, añadí comentarios para darle un mayor entendimiento a lo que busco realizar.

```
%Estos hechos debo cambiarlos por listas para optimizar mi programa
cuenta(4552, 452, 5000).
cuenta(2554, 254, 5000).

nip(452, 4552).
nip(254, 2554).

%Esta regla debe evaluar los datos ingresados en la regla "iniciar" para poder compararlos con los datos de la lista y corroborar que sean elementos de la misma lista.
evainicio(X, Y):- cuenta(X, Y), nip(Y, X), menu; false.

%Aquí el usuario ingresa los datos de su cuenta que deben coincidir con los elementos correspondientes a la misma lista
iniciar :- write('No. de Cuenta: '),
    read(X),
    write('NIP: '),
    read(Y), evainicio(X, Y).

%Las funciones de Menu y ejecutar(Opcion), simplemente evalúan el numero ingresado por el usuario para llamar la regla correspondiente y ejecutarla, no involucran a las listas.
menu :- write('***BANCO***'),nl,
    write('1. Consultar saldo'),nl,
    write('2. Retirar'),nl,
    write('3. Depositar'),nl,
    write('4. Traspasar'),nl,
    write('5. Estado de cuenta'),nl,
    write('6. Cambiar NIP'),nl,
    write('7. Salir'),nl,
    write('Seleccione una opcion: '),read(Opcion),ejecutar(Opcion).

ejecutar(Opcion) :- Opcion =<0, write('Opcion no valida'), nl, menu;
                    Opcion == 1, consultar, menu;
                    Opcion == 2, retirar, menu;
                    Opcion == 3, depositar, menu;
                    Opcion == 4, traspasar, menu;
                    Opcion == 5, estado, menu;
                    Opcion == 6, cambiarnip, menu;
                    Opcion == 7, true;
                    Opcion >=8, write('Opcion no valida'), nl, menu.

consultar :- %En esta regla debería llamar el elemento 3 de la lista para imprimirlo como el saldo vínculado a los datos ingresados en la regla iniciar.

%En retirar, llamar al 3er elemento de la lista y restarle la cantidad ingresada aquí mismo para después actualizar el 3er elemento con el resultado de la resta.
retirar :- write('Ingrese el primer numero: '),
    read(X),
    write('Ingrese el segundo numero: '),
    read(Y),Z is X-Y,
    format('El resultado es ~w', Z).
```

Intente realizar las listas de esta forma "cuenta([No, de Cuenta, NIP, Saldo])" y evaluarlas así "evaluar(X, Y) :- cuenta([X|Y]), cuenta(W, [X|Y]), menu; false."; evidentemente no funciono para evaluar y trono el programa.

Comment: No es necesario usar listas, aquí te hice un ejemplo: https://javapro.org/programming-languages/crud-en-prolog/

Comment: He leído el enlace y muchisimas gracias por la ayuda, intentare hacerlo con esta información, un saludo.